# Pass query result to another class

Tags: php, class

When I do a query in class A, I got all data already. class B need to use some of the data. I prefer pass part of the query result to B than do a new query in B. Class B will perform some jobs and the data will be changed in class B. **How to pass the array $something_else** to class B? Here is the classes:

```
class A{
  public $something;
  private $_project_obj;
  function __construct( $id = null ){
    if ( $id ) {
       $this->id = $id;
       $this->populate( $this->id );
    }
}
 function populate(){
      $query = //do query
      $this->somthing= $query['A'];
      $this->something_else = $query['B'];
}
 function save(){
     // call save() in class B, $something_else is saved there
     if ( $this->_project_obj instanceof B ) {
    if ( true !== $this->_project_obj->save() ) {
        return false;
    }
    }
    // save $something and other stuffs in class A
   //  ......
   }
  function project() {  
    if ( !$this->_project_obj instanceof B ) {
     if ( ( $this->id ) && ( loggedin_user_id() ) ) {
       $this->_project_obj = new B( $this->id, loggedin_user_id() );
    } else {
    return false;
    }
    }
     return $this->_project_obj
    }
}
class B{
  public $data_this;
  public $data_that;
  function __constructor( $id=null, $user_id=null){
      if($id && $user_id){
        return $this->populate();
      }
      return true;

  }
 function populate(){
  $query = // do the same query as in class A
  $something_else = $query['B'];
  $this->data_this = $something_else['a'];
  $this->data_that = $something_else['b'];
 }
 function save(){
  // save all data as $something_else 
 }
 function jobs(){
 // perform jobs
 }
}
```

Comment: "How to pass the array $something_else" ...to what? It's not clear what's needing to happen here.

Comment: to class B. Except class B need the data, noothing else need to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear *where* in B you're needing `something_else`, so let's just add it as part of the constructor: Make the constructor function accept an additional parameter of `something_else` and save it to that class' property:

```
class B{
  private var $_parent;
  function __constructor( $parent, $id=null, $user_id=null){
      $this->_parent = $parent; // Save reference to the "A" that contains this "B"
      if($id && $user_id){
        return $this->populate();
      }
      return true;

  }
```

When A creates a B: `$this->_project_obj = new B( $this, $this->id, loggedin_user_id() );`

And when B needs to get the latest version of `something_else` from its parent A: `$this->_parent->something_else`

Comment: Probably this is the solution for me. Would you please help me check my code to see-- if use this solution, when jobs are performing in class B and saved, will class B still use the old $something_else that received from class A ? I need the $something_else updated after perform the jobs.

Comment: @Jenny you haven't posted any code for how `B` performs the jobs, so I have no way of telling you whether or not it uses `$something_else` properly. Overall, I don't see why you have two classes in the first place, as it seems to be duplicating many similar functions and complicating things.

Comment: class A is an object to create content, class B is an object to handle user's various settings about this post. The 2 class both work on the same post_id. but their jobs does not interact with each other.

Comment: If the content being created by A and edited by B is the same object, there should be one class with two methods (`edit` and `new`), such that they share the same database query results (and the same `save`) function that has results from both.

Comment: the post is the same, but the content and the settings are quite different objects. and the save() methods are different, the save() in class A need to work with a service that provided by another software. the save() in class B need to work with user's choices by ajax. In addition, class A works with author_id, class B's job is performed by visitor_id.

Comment: I've updated my code such that A passes a reference to itself, so B can always get at its current `something_else`, even if it's been updated since B was created.

Comment: Immediately after B was updated, I need to get A updated, the two save are both performed when B updated.

Comment: Then have `B::save()` call `$this->_parent->populate()` after it's done, to have A fetch the updated data.

Answer (score 0):

```
class class_b
{

public $something_else = NULL

}

$a = new class_a();
$b = new class_b();

$b->something_else = $a->something_else
```

Comment: where should I write down the $b ? if not inside class A, I will still do a new query?

Comment: `$b` is the instance of your class. So instead of `$b`, use whatever instance you make when you perform your stuff.

Comment: $something_else has to be queried from database or passed from class A. That's the relationship I need to sort out.

Comment: So you want to pass the `something_else` property from class a to class B?

Comment: for example, $something_else=array([0]=>3,[1]=>5), the 3 and 5 is the data needed in class B.